# Installing Ruby on Rails Using Rvm in offline mode on CentOS 6.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, rvm, offline

I am following the steps given in the (https://github.com/rvm/rvm-site/blob/master/content/rvm/offline.md) but I feel that rvm isn't getting installed with the `./install --auto-dotfiles` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The problem was i used other OS's file.